# Seeking Help: python2.7: working on this function; want to get input from "def proceed3()" to "def openChrome()"

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, gae-python27

How do i pass my **website_name** which is a URL, https://www.google.com/ for instance; from **"def proceed3()"** to **"def openChrome()"** ? Any Suggestions?

```
from Tkinter import *


def proceed3():
    popup = Toplevel()
    popup.geometry("350x175+350+180")
    popup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    instruction = Label(popup, text="Enter the URL and pressGO!").pack()
    website_name = Entry(popup, width=50).pack(pady=5)
    goButton = Button(popup, text="GO!", command=openChrome)
    goButton.pack(pady=5)


def openChrome():
    openWebsite = website_name.get()
    os.system(r"start chrome " + openWebsite)


windows = Tk()

windows.geometry("200x200+375+280")
windows.resizable(width=False, height=False)



submitButton = Button(windows, text='OpenChrome', command=proceed3)
submitButton.pack(pady=5)

windows.mainloop()
```

TRACEBACK ERROR:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\lib\lib-tk\Tkinter.py", line 1542, in __call__
return self.func(*args)
File "E:/educational_data/PyCharmProjects/web_grabber/starflow_grabber.py", 
line 15, in openChrome
openWebsite = website_name.get()
NameError: global name 'website_name' is not defined
```

Comment: I get the feeling that you're missing something important about functions:  they can take arguments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> want to get input from `def proceed3()` to `def openChrome()`.

The problem can be fixed.

For Python 2.7, Use Tkinter.

For Python 3.x, Use tkinter.

Avoid wildcard `import *`. Use this import tkinter as `tk` then use prefix `tk.` for widgets.

- Add namespace `import os`.
- On line 8, move instruction outside of function and place `windows.resizable`.
- On line 9, move `website_name` outside of function and place `windows.resizable`.
- On tk.Entry, split into 2 lines. So we can pass the website_name to
  `def openChrome()`
- Both `tk Entry(popup,..)` and `tk.Label(popup,..)` to both `tk Entry(windows,..)` and `tk.Label(windows,..)`.

Run the script.

Snippet:

```
import Tkinter as tk . #For Python 2.7
import tkinter as tk. #For Python 3.x
import os


def proceed3():
    popup = tk.Toplevel()
    popup.geometry("350x175+350+180")
    popup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
     
    goButton = tk.Button(popup, text=" Press GO!", command=openChrome)
    goButton.pack(pady=5)


def openChrome():
    openWebsite = website_name.get()
    os.system(r"start chrome " + openWebsite)


windows = tk.Tk()

windows.geometry("400x200")
windows.resizable(width=False, height=False)

instruction = tk.Label(windows, text="Enter the URL and press openChrome button!").pack()

website_name = tk.Entry(windows, width=50)
website_name.pack(pady=5)

submitButton = tk.Button(windows, text='OpenChrome', command=proceed3)
submitButton.pack(pady=5)

windows.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add 
`return website_name` to the end of your proceed3() function

Add an argument `website_name` to your OpenChrome() function.

```
def proceed3():
    popup = Toplevel()
    popup.geometry("350x175+350+180")
    popup.resizable(width=False, height=False)
    instruction = Label(popup, text="Enter the URL and pressGO!").pack()
    website_name = Entry(popup, width=50).pack(pady=5)
    goButton = Button(popup, text="GO!", command=openChrome)
    goButton.pack(pady=5)
    return website_name


def openChrome(website_name):
    os.system(r"start chrome " + website_name)
```

I would suggest reading [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_functions.htm) regarding how to work with functions in python, as this will be fundamental to furthering your programming efforts.

Comment: This didn't work I've read the post you sent and tried couple of times with absolute failure.... Anyone else out there can help? I really appreciate everyone's who helped and will help in future.

Comment: A return statement on a function called from a button is useless. Where do you think the value is being returned to? Also, you can't add an argument to a function definition unless you also pass an argument to that function when it's being called. Your code example doesn't show how to do that.